# Exercise 2.2 in P. Coleman's Introduction to Many-Body Physics

Tags: solid-state-physics, many-body

I am self-reading P. Coleman's *Introduction to Many-Body Physics*. In Exercise 2.2, we are asked to prove the following orthogonality relation
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} e^{i(q_{n}-q_{m})ja} = \frac{(-1)^{(n-m)(N-1)}}{N} \frac{\sin{\pi(n-m)}}{\sin{\frac{\pi}{N}(n-m)}} = \delta_{n,m},
\end{align}
where $q_{n} = n \frac{2\pi}{Na}$ is the discrete wave vector. I proceed as in the instruction by treating this summation as a geometric series and I have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} e^{i\frac{2\pi(n-m)}{N}j} &= \frac{1}{N} \frac{1-e^{i{2\pi(n-m)}}}{1-e^{i\frac{2\pi(n-m)}{N}}} = \frac{1}{N} \frac{e^{i\pi(n-m)}}{e^{i\pi(n-m)/N}} \frac{e^{-i\pi(n-m)}-e^{i\pi(n-m)}}{e^{-i\pi(n-m)/N}-e^{i\pi(n-m)/N}}=\frac{1}{N} \frac{e^{i\pi(n-m)}}{e^{i\pi(n-m)/N}} \frac{\sin\pi(n-m)}{\sin{\frac{\pi}{N}(n-m)}} \\
& = \frac{1}{N} e^{i\pi(n-m)(1-\frac{1}{N})}\frac{\sin\pi(n-m)}{\sin{\frac{\pi}{N}(n-m)}}=\frac{1}{N} e^{i\pi(n-m)(\frac{N-1}{N})}\frac{\sin\pi(n-m)}{\sin{\frac{\pi}{N}(n-m)}}.
\end{align}
But I am not sure whether this is equal to
\begin{align}
\frac{(-1)^{(n-m)(N-1)}}{N} \frac{\sin{\pi(n-m)}}{\sin{\frac{\pi}{N}(n-m)}}
\end{align}
since I think
\begin{align}
e^{i\pi(n-m)(\frac{N-1}{N})} \neq (-1)^{(n-m)(N-1)}.
\end{align}
Is there any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: It's possible this is a typo in the book, since you would end up with the orthogonality relationship regardless of whether the exponent had a factor of $N-1$ or $(N-1)/N$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah that is my concern. I know that my result will also lead to the orthogonality condition, but the fact that I obtain different stuff in the intermediate state makes me wonder whether I miss something. So I will just check if someone also agree with my calculation here.

Comment: For what it's worth, I didn't see a problem with any of your steps, so I think you are right. At the very least, your approach is sound and should work.

Comment: Since you're self-studying Coleman's book, it's worth mentioning that it has very many typos. It might be helpful to have one or two alternative resources at your side, in case you run into a trickier typo.

Comment: It's not uncommon for books or lectures to have mistakes precisely in the intermediate steps. It's easy to be blind to them as an author/lecturer, as long as the end result is what you know it should be.

Comment: The intermediate result is correct, but probably a typo, and completely unnecessary.

Comment: You can see it is correct since for $n\neq m$, the $\sin(\pi(n-m)$ is zero, so it doesn't matter if the other factors agree in this case. For $n=m$, presumably you are supposed to take the limit, so the ratio of sines is $N$, and the minus one factor has a zero exponent, so the intermediate result gives the correct answer. Of course this manipulation into sines is all useless work. Your first expression shows that for $m \neq n$ the result is zero. For $m=n$, all the summand terms are 1 giving the desired result.